# Replace values in pandas column with lists by values in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with column that contains lists with id of objects and objects alias in other dataframe. I want to replace `id` in column with lists in first dataframe by `alias` from second.

First:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'objects': ['', '', '']})
df.objects[0] = []
df.objects[1] = ['2309b0ec-047f-43ef',
                     'a6150d80-49fa-11e9',
                     'c103f8b0-4ac0-11e9',
                     'e8c9db30-4ac0-11e9']
df.objects[2] = ['b14424df-1a46-4e30']
```

```
print(df)
                                                     objects
        0                                                 []
        1                    [2309b0ec-047f-43ef, a6150d8...
        2                               [b14424df-1a46-4e30]
```

Second:

```
objects = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['2309b0ec-047f-43ef',
                               'a6150d80-49fa-11e9',
                               'c103f8b0-4ac0-11e9',
                               'e8c9db30-4ac0-11e9',
                               'b14424df-1a46-4e30'],
                        'alias': ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']})
```

```
print(objects)
                               id   alias
            0  2309b0ec-047f-43ef   first
            1  a6150d80-49fa-11e9  second
            2  c103f8b0-4ac0-11e9  third
            3  e8c9db30-4ac0-11e9  fourth
            4  b14424df-1a46-4e30   fifth
```

Desire output:

```
                          objects
0                              []
1  [first, second, third, fourth]
2                         [fifth]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft a mapping series and loop:

```
s = objects.set_index('id')['alias']

df['objects'] = [[s.get(x) for x in l] for l in df['objects']]
```

Output:

```
                          objects
0                              []
1  [first, second, third, fourth]
2                         [fifth]
```

NB. You could also `explode`, `map` and aggregate again (`df['objects'].explode().map(s).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist())`) but this would be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
d=dict(objects.values)
df.applymap(lambda x:[d[y] for y in x])
```